# Bash memory "leak" when recursing directories

Tags: linux, macos, bash, fat32, hfs+

I'm currently trying to write a script that does some post processing after `rsync --max-size=4000000000` has done its job, to allow for full backups to FAT32 (which is the only filesystem that is r/w on all of Windows/Mac/*nix)

I am writing in bash for Mac OS X and Linux; currently testing on OS X. Code is here

https://github.com/taikedz/fullsync32/blob/master/fullsync32

The script recurses through directories finding

- files that have a resource fork (HFS property)
- files that are larger than 4 GB

and upon finding such files either processes them via `tar -cz` or `split` as appropriate, before copying them over.

I use recursion instead of the `find` utility because of the test for presence of resource fork on a file: it involves checking the size of a special file. Say you have file foo.txt; its resource fork can be found by looking at `ls -l foo.txt/..namedfork/rsrc` and cheking the length is non-zero.

The basic structure is

```
recurse() {
  pushd "$1"
    for NODE in *; do
      if [ -d "$NODE" ]; then
        recurse "$NODE"
        continue
      fi
      # (process files here, with calls to split, tar and md5)
    done
  popd
}

recurse ./target/directory
```

### Problem

I ran this against my backups the other day and left it running for a few hours. When I came back I found that my spare 11 GB of RAM had been used up, and it was ~248 MB into swap...

I looked around on Google for issues around bash memory leakage in recursion, and apart from a few tenuously answered forum posts, didn't find much...

The other add result of which (which is Mac specific) is that the "Inactive memory" stays inactive and the system runs slowly... Restart required.

### Questions

- Is such potentially deep recursion with bash a bad idea in itself?
- is there an ingenious way to iterate rather than recurse in this situation?
- or am I going about this completely wrong anyways?

You inputs are much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe someone can flesh this out into a proper answer, but why not write a script hat takes a filepath, and does the processing on the files as required, and then use find to call this with each file using -exec?

Comment: First, I wouldn't use pushd/popd at all here -- frankly, they aren't needed; you can use `cd ..` and have the stack be implicit.

Second, be very, very sure you aren't traversing symlinks. `[ -d . ]` will be true, but if you `pushd .`, you're adding another level...

Comment: Also, if you track the stack yourself (as in a shell array), you can print it, so you can *see* (or log) where space is being used, where if anywhere you're looping endlessly, what the current depth is, etc.

Comment: Save yourself some lines with this one weird trick! (The glob `*/` expands only to directories.)

Comment: @SpoonMeiser - unless you can clarify how to use `find` to perform the test (`find any file that has ..namedfork/rsrc of length greater than zero`), that solution unfortunately does not apply... but if there is indeed a way then that'd save a lot of trouble....!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy pushd vs cd -- you are right. D'oh!

Also thank you for tip on symlinks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The `DIRSTACK` array is updated by `pushd` and `popd`.

Comment: Is `NODE` being defined as a function local variable in your original script? It isn't in the snippet here and that is going to cause all sorts of unintended behaviour problems (though not leaking problems).

Comment: How would `cd` work here without using a sub-shell per directory?

Comment: @EtanReisner Since you always cd to an immediate child directory, you can always `cd ..` to go back.

Comment: @thatotherguy Ah, I missed that being specified in the answer. I don't see how that's better than pushd/popd though.

Comment: My point was that if you can execute a script on every file, you don't have to get find to only pick the ones you want - that script can check the file and decide to either do something or not do something. Not a great solution, admittedly, which is why I've not actually put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is such potentially deep recursion with bash a bad idea in itself?

Bash is not meant for recursion, but has no problems recursing to a few thousand levels which is more than sufficient for recursing through a filesystem.

However, Bash, like all languages, are unable to do non-tail recursion to infinite depths like you risk by foregoing `find`'s proven cycle detection.

> is there an ingenious way to iterate rather than recurse in this situation?

You can iterate over `find` output:

```
find "$1" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r filename
do
  echo "Operating on $filename"
done
```

> how to use find to perform the test

You can run arbitrary external tests with `-exec`, here invoking bash:

```
find / -exec bash -c '[[ -s "$1/..namedfork/rsrc" ]]' _ {} \; -print
```

Comment: Returning to his after a while - the find command as listed is exactly what I was looking for it seems... Though I still have to study it to figure out what you did there...

Many thanks